# How to tie an ArcGIS Server QueryTask result back to the calling layer?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, ajax, query-task

Using ArcGIS Server JS API 4.x I'm running a series of QueryTasks in succession, and need to tie the result of the query back to the calling layer. However, since the QueryTasks execute asynchronously I'm not sure which result corresponds to which QueryTask.

To illustrate the issue I created a simple [example](https://codepen.io/slead/pen/qBbjeoy) on CodePen which writes the results of the query to the console.

Open the debugging tools and note that the result of the QueryTask has no information as to which layer the results apply to:

```
require([
  "esri/tasks/QueryTask",
  "esri/tasks/support/Query"
], function(QueryTask, Query) {

 var config = {
   "layer1": {
        "url": "https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/WorldTimeZones/MapServer/0"
    },
    "layer2": {
        "url": "https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/911CallsHotspot/MapServer/1"
    },
   "layer3": {
        "url": "https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/LocalGovernment/SewerManholeInspections/FeatureServer/0"
   }
}
 
for (layerDef in config){
    var queryTask = new QueryTask({url: config[layerDef].url});
    var query = new Query();
    query.where = "1=1";

    // These execute asynchronously so there is no way to tie the result back to the calling query
    console.log("about to check count for", layerDef);

    queryTask.execute(query).then(function(results){
        // How to detect which layer this result corresponds to?
        console.log("Count:", results)
    });
}
```

How can I determine to which layer the results correspond? I guess I need a separate callback function for each queryTask - but I can't see how to specify this.

PS. Here I'm using `queryTask.executeForCount` but the same applies if I use a simple `queryTask.execute`, and the principle should hopefully be the same anyway.

PPS. An option could be to make an AJAX request directly against the server URL, but due to the environment I'm working in that fails due to CORS issues, so I'm stuck using the QueryTask approach

Comment: Please post code as formatted text using the `{}` button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by sending the LayerName along with the QueryTask to a separate function.

```
for (layerDef in config){
    var queryTask = new QueryTask({url: config[layerDef].url});
    var query = new Query();
    query.where = "1=1";

    getResults(query, layerDef).then(function(results){
      console.log(results[0], "returned", results[1], "features");
    });
}

function getResults(query, layername){
    return queryTask.executeForCount(query).then(function(results){
      return [layername,results];
    });
}
```

Comment: Please post code as formatted text using the `{}` button

Comment: wow, many thanks for the fast response. I edited your post to include the actual code, and I also updated it on the Codepen link. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem, glad to help!